# Unconstrained type parameters casting

Tags: c#, .net, types, casting

My situation:

```
interface ISomeInterface {
    void DoSmth<T>(T other);
}

class Base : ISomeInterface
{
    public virtual void DoSmth<T>(T other){
        // for example do nothing
    }
}

class Derived<T2> : Base {
    Action<T2> MyAction {get;set;}

    public override void DoSmth<T>(T other){
        if(typeof(T2).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
            MyAction((T2) other);
    }
}
```

This gives me an error: `Cannot cast expression of type 'T' to type 'T2'` (or `Cannot convert type 'T' to 'T2'`)

I understand that it is because neither T or T2 are constrained with `class`, but if I know - due to `IsAssignableFrom` - that I can use T where I need T2, how can I convince compiler to allow it?

Comment: `(T2)(object) other`

Comment: `(T2) (object) other`

Comment: Yup, you guys are right - I got this idea just seconds after posting ;) Write an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: In Java, you could give T and T2 a common interface and use that instead. Could that help here as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler sees the T2 and T identifiers and helpfully informs you that those types seem unrelated. That's absolutely correct, as they have no relation: there are no generic constraints that would assert any relations between them (I'm not saying that would be useful here though :) ).

Whether this is a good feature or not, is disputable. Sometimes I'd like it to be just a warning, but in most cases, it's helpful to have it be a compilation error. Number of such casts in generic classes is much lower than number of typos in 'normal' code :)

Solution is very very simple. Just cheat the compiler to know nothing about **the source** type, and it will skip the type hierarchy checks against destination type:

```
T theTee = ...;
object temp = (object)theTee;
T2 teeTwo = (T2)temp; // ok! 'temp' is now seen as 'object'
```

or in one liner:

```
T2 teeTwo = (T2)(object)theTee;
```

similarly, you can use `dynamic` (if it's available at your .Net version):

```
T theTee = ...;
dynamic temp = theTee;
T2 teeTwo = temp;
```

and oneliner should work too:

```
T2 teeTwo = (dynamic)theTee;
```

though I have never tried that one, as I think it's heavier than cast-via-object. I haven't checked performance of object/dynamic approaches though. Just a hunch.

Comment: As I was reading my first though about dynamic was - it's probably worse performance-wise. I guess I'll go for (T2)(object) - I've added a comment explaining myself to "future generations". If I do it only after `IsAssignableFrom == true` then it should always work, shouldn't it?

Comment: From what I remember, `IsAssignableFrom` is the best Type-vs-Type check you can get. However, from time to time, the name `IsAssignableFrom` vs `IsCastable` bothers mee to. I don't remember any case when being `AssignableFrom` wouldn't cause `Castability`. I can't tell you I'm absolutely sure. I can think of some very rare corner cases where something strange could happen, however, I don't see nor remember any case where it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Gerino: So, I'm strongly convinced that `IsAssignableFrom` implies "Castability", in this direction. However, those terms are not equal. I *believe* that `IsAssignableFrom` can get you at least some **false negatives**. For example, a `__ComObject` can be actually castable at runtime to interfaces, but I don't think it's type would be `IsAssignableFrom` into those interface types. Never checked though. Might be interesting to check msdn articles for that case.

Comment: mmhm, false negatives with COM seem to be a fact - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885002/isassignablefrom-with-com Fortunatelly, as I said, I never heard of false positives :)

Comment: I'll cross that bridge when I get to it, I guess - the types SHOULD be fairly non-exotic (primitives, model classes), and honestly in MOST cases T == T2 - I don't want to close the ability to have a bit more general implementations for, e.g., `Model : ModelBase` and `OtherModel : ModelBase` :)